# Whether to use methods or edit properties with Interface Builder directly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have to set the properties like font and color for a button in my iOS application. Would it be better to set these in code using public methods like **getButtonTextFont()** and **getButtonTextColor()** OR should I simply set the properties by using the Interface Builder's utility window?

***Note***: These properties are static and will not change during the course of application.

Also, please suggest the correct naming convention for these methods if they are required.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

The properties can be easily set for different states of the buttons.
Steps:

1. Select the .xib file containing the button
2. Select the button and enable the Utility area by using the View
   segment bar at upper right corner.
3. Open the attributes inspector
4. Select the state for which you want to set the properties of the
   button by using "state config" drop down.
5. Change the properties for each of the required states accordingly.

You can still use the following methods to change the properties:

> +(UIFont*)getButtonsTextFont14Bold{
>       return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14]; }
>
> +(UIColor*) getButtonsTextColorWhite{
>
> ```
> return [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1]; }
> ```

Comment: this doesn't answer *Whether to use methods or edit properties with Interface Builder*

Answer (score 1):

If these are static properties don't generate code for them just set them in the XIB.

Your white color can also be obtained with the `UIColor` class method aptly named whiteColor.

```
[UIColor whiteColor];
```

As for naming conventions within Objective-C I would go over this guide from Apple called [Programming with Objective-C: Conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html).